# Visual Studio 2010 - Does not copy folder on deployment to "Out" directory

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, deployment

Hi I need copy folder which contains XML configuration files for IoC in Unit Test Projects to TestResults "output" directory. I use Visual Studio 2010.

Visual Studion solution has this structure:

- MyProject (Solution)

  - MyProject.Tests (Unit Test Project)

    - CoreSettings (folder which contains XML files, I need copy this folder to **MyProject.Tests\bin\debug\TestResults\test_XXX\out**)

First I tried edit this two files:

- Local.testsettings
- TraceAndTestImpact.testsettings

I opened these two configuration files in VS and:

- chose Deployment >> Add Directory and  added in both configuration files folder  CorreSettings.

I ran test but **folder CoreSettings** was not copy to **MyProject.Tests\bin\debug\TestResults\test_XXX\out**.

I google it and found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/3588829/1110195.

So I edited these files :

- Local.testsettings
- TraceAndTestImpact.testsettings

And added this:

```
<DeploymentItem filename="MyProject.Tests\CoreSettings\" outputDirectory="CoreSettings\">
```

But it didn’t help.

I tried used attribute way.

on test class I added.

```
 [DeploymentItem(@"MyProject.Tests\CoreSettings, @"CoreSettings\")]
```

But also this way didn’t copy folder CoreSettings to TestRestults\test_XXX\out.

In TestRestults\test_XXX\out I found and DLL’s but not CoreSettings folder.

All XML files in CoreSettings folder has:

- Build Action: Content
- Copy to Output Directory: Copy always

What I do bad? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and got the answer from the linked question. I had to change (using your example)

```
<DeploymentItem filename="MyProject.Tests\CoreSettings\" outputDirectory="CoreSettings\">
```

to

```
<DeploymentItem filename="CoreSettings\" outputDirectory="CoreSettings\">
```